# Can you re-use buffers with Windows wave audio input?

Tags: windows, audio, multimedia, wave

I'm using the Windows multimedia APIs to record and process wave audio (`waveInOpen` and friends).  I'd like to use a small number of buffers in a round robin fashion.

I know that you're supposed to use `waveInPrepareHeader` before adding a buffer to the device, and that you're supposed to call `waveInUnprepareHeader` after the wave device has "returned the buffer to the application" and before you deallocate it.

My question is, do I have to unprepare and re-prepare in order to re-use a buffer?  Or can I just add a previously used buffer back to the device?

Also, does it matter what thread I do this on?  I'm using the callback function, which seems to be called on a worker thread that belongs to the audio system.  Can I call `waveInUnprepareHeader`, `waveInPrepareHeader`, and `waveInAddBuffer` on that thread, during the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, my experience has been you need to call prepare and unprepare every time. From memory, it returns an error if you try to reuse the same one.

And you typically call the prepare and unprepare on whatever thread you are handling the callbacks on.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like trying to call waveInUnprepare during the callback is a problem during a waveInReset--it causes a deadlock.

Comment: yes, deadlocks in waveInReset (and waveOutReset) are a pain, and vary depending on what sound card driver you have.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the buffers, call `waveInPrepareHeader`. Then you can simply set the **prepared** flag before you call `waveInAddBuffer` on a buffer that was returned from the device.

```
pHdr->dwFlags = WHDR_PREPARED;
```

You can do this on the callback thread (or in the message handler).

Comment: In my tests, the the dwFlags field has WHDR_PREPARED even after the device has finished with the buffer, so I'm not sure exactly what meaning that field has.  I suppose it might vary with the sound driver.

Comment: It may also vary between different versions of Windows AFAIK. At any rate, I've never had a problem calling waveInAddBuffer without the calls to waveInUnprepareHeader and waveInPrepareHeader.